# Possible to use hasFocus binding in Knockout to determine table current row index

Tags: knockout.js

I would like to know which row in the table the user has navigated to or clicked on.

Can Knockout's `hasFocus` binding be used to track the current row index, so that inside the view model I can get that row index value as needed?

The table is populated in this manner:

```
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: sitesList">
        <tr>
             <td data-bind ... > </td>
             <td data-bind ... > </td>
                .
                .
                .

               et cetera
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably a better way to do this but...

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: sitesList">
        <tr data-bind="event: { focusout: $parent.updateSelectedRow }">
             <td data-bind="text: $data"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

Index: <span data-bind="text: selectedRowIndex"></span>
```

JS:

```
function ViewModel()
{
    var self = this;
    self.selectedRowIndex = ko.observable();
    self.sitesList = ko.observableArray(["google.com", "bing.com", "yahoo.com"]);

    self.updateSelectedRow = function(row)
    {
        self.selectedRowIndex(self.sitesList.indexOf(row));
    };
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Here is a link to a fiddle that demonstrates it working: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueEddie/L3YP4/2/

**EDIT:**

Changed it to use event binding.  I got it working with mouseenter.  Maybe you could use the onfocus event instead?

Comment: It doesn't capture TAB key navigation.

Comment: Changed to use event binding.  Works with mouseenter.

Comment: Thanks for both suggestions, but `event:mouseenter` isn't working reliably with TAB key navigation either,-subsequent changed positions are not being recorded. It's also firing many times, unnecessarily, when the user moves the mouse down the page to reach a specific row.

Comment: Can you create a js fiddle with your code so I can see if I can figure something out?

Comment: OK, I am away for the weekend but will put something up on Monday. What I had been doing was capturing a click on a button in a cell and figuring out the rowindex using jQuery. But users don't want a button. They want something that resembles Microsoft Access grid view, whose update event fires when the row loses focus.

Comment: Got it working with knockout  `event` binding on TR `focusout`.  Change your answer to that event, and I can accept it  :-)